# Piece of SQL code moves when I try to save the view I edited

Tags: sql-server

I hope I'm asking this correctly because I don't use Stack Overflow much, but no one here can help me with this.
I wrote this query and it seems to work fine, but when I paste it into a new view and hit the save button, it corrupts the code. SQL Server Management Studio 18.5

This:

```
FROM            dbo.AR_Options) AS A ON dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.ARDivisionNo = A.ARDivisionNo
    WHERE (CONVERT(varchar(7), dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.TransactionDate, 120) <> CurrentFiscalYr + '-' + CurrentPeriod) 
AND (dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.DateUpdated >= '2015-11-01') 
AND (GETDATE() - dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.DateUpdated <= 7)
```

gets turned into this:

```
FROM            dbo.AR_Options) AS A ON dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.ARDivisionNo = A.ARDivisionNo AND CONVERT(varchar(7), dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.TransactionDate, 120) 
                         <> A.CurrentPeriod + '-' + A.CurrentFiscalYr
WHERE        (dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.DateUpdated >= '2015-11-01') 
AND (GETDATE() - dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.DateUpdated <= 7)
```

Notice how this piece of code jumped up into the FROM section: `dbo.AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader.TransactionDate, 120)  <> CurrentFiscalYr + '-' + CurrentPeriod`.  All I did was hit the 'save' button and that happened.
Any advice?  I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.  Thank you in advance for your help.

update:  I took the advice and scripted a new view (right click on 'view'>Script to > CREATE TO) but unfortunately it did the same thing

update:  I think i resolved it.  What I did was add the code snippet into the table-thing in the filters section (see pic below).  it added the code in the correct place in the WHERE statement.
[image]

update:  Actually, no that didn't work.  It let me save it but when i reopened the view in design mode it moved the code again.  Sigh...

Comment: FYI, 3 part naming for columns is due to be deprecated and should be avoided. Using aliases and then qualifying your columns with that also makes your code way more succinct.

Comment: SSMS is refactoring your query. Don't use it, just create your view in a query window.

Comment: If you are using the view designer I suggest not. Just script view, alter and manually change. The designer falls over after anything less than very simple.